# cert-manager not resolving challenge : Waiting for HTTP-01 challenge propagation: wrong status code '401', expected '200'

Tags: google-cloud-platform, kubernetes-ingress, cert-manager, gke-networking

I am using GKE for my services and few of my services use ALB in GCP.
I use below ingress to create the ALB and it works fine. but when I look at challenge it is failing with error in description and `cm-acme-http-solver` is also not getting resolved because of that.

I search a lot on google and I did not find people getting this error much.
When we deployed service,2 months back this type of error did not pop up and it has been just last 7 days since we the challenge is failing.

There is no such log I find for `challenges` `orders`. only the error.
Do I need to add any port access that is blocking the ALB in GCP to access GKE
note:MY GKE cluster is private.

How I set up ingress:

```
ingress:
  enabled: true
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: 'gce'
  hosts:
    - host: myhost.com
      paths:
        - path: /
          pathType: Prefix
  tls:
    - hosts:
        - myhost.com.com
      secretName: customer-secret-tls
```

Comment: This issue has already occurred for few users in the past times, as it has occurred for only few there is no proper documentation or issues for this error, try adding [acme.cert-manager.io/http01-edit-in-place:](http://acme.cert-manager.io/http01-edit-in-place:) "true" in the annotations of ingress. You can open a new issue on the [issue tracker](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers) describing your issue.

Comment: I think problem is that lets encrypt does not support gce class directly and I would need to switch to gcp self managed certification

Comment: It may work by using external-dns with static credentials as described in [[link](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/external-dns/blob/master/docs/tutorials/gke.md)] and Let's encrypt with GCE ingress using a static IP and manually created DNS entry as described in [[link](https://cert-manager.io/docs/tutorials/getting-started-with-cert-manager-on-google-kubernetes-engine-using-lets-encrypt-for-ingress-ssl/)].

Comment: thanks @SaiChandraGadde. Now I took a different route, because I am using ALB so I added the GCP managed ssl certificate to load balancer with this annotation and it seems to recognize it `ingress.gcp.kubernetes.io/pre-shared-cert`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So because I was using the ALB and then letsencrypt as self managed certificate in GCP, while its a best practice to use GCP managed certificate   for ALB.

Solution that I applied and resolved the issue is:

I created a certificate in GCP
Then I annotated that in my ingress as below

`ingress.gcp.kubernetes.io/pre-shared-cert`

This annotation will attach the GCP managed certificate to my load balancer.