# While Adding GCP managed certificate to Application load balancer ingress only shows port 80

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, load-balancing, kubernetes-ingress

I am facing a strange issue.

I have an application running on GKE.. It creates an ALB (classic) in GCP.
I have created a certificate in GCP and I added that certificate to ALB using annotation . it got added and I can see when I call the ingress that certificate is in use.

Now problem is that in my GKE when I check `kubectl get ingress`  I see only port `80` and not `80,443`

Is this expected behaviour or there is an issue . and if this is issue how to solve it ?
my ingress manifest

```
ingress:
  enabled: true
  annotations:
    ingress.gcp.kubernetes.io/pre-shared-cert: certificate-name-ssl
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: 'gce'
  hosts:
    - host: api.hostname.com
      paths:
        - backend:
              service:
                name: my-service
                port:
                  number: 8080
        - path: /
          pathType: Prefix
```

If I add tis certificate to load balancer it does show port `80,443`

Comment: aside from this behavior are you having any issue regarding the certificate? or everything is working fine it is just it doesnt show 443 when you check ingress?

Comment: only that is doesn't show 443. And that is because there is no tis and when we look for ingress api response it only respond with port 80
I did fix this issue
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77992806/cert-manager-not-resolving-challenge-waiting-for-http-01-challenge-propagation?noredirect=1#comment137541746_77992806

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe its a normal behavior, upon checking this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/managed-certs#setting_up_a_google-managed_certificate)  wherein there is a step to create a Google managed SSL certificate, once the yaml with annotation of the google managed certificate manifested then applied to cluster, the step performed `kubectl get ingress` and got the same result as yours. These steps can be seen from the link I shared.